# Flink keyBy over option list

Tags: apache-flink

My dummy flink job

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.json4s.NoTypeHints
import org.json4s.native.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.read

case class Label(name: String, typ: String)
case class MyData(id: String, labels: Option[List[Label]] )

object WindowWordCount {
  implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  env.getConfig.setParallelism(1)

  val packetSource = env
      .socketTextStream("localhost", 7777)
      .map(json => read[MyData](json))

  env.execute("Window Stream WordCount")
  }
}
```

So, each `MyData` object have unique `id` and can have multiple `labels`.
What im going to do is do `.keyBy` by label.

Incoming data example (serialized to `MyData`)

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "labels": [
    {
      "name": "unolabelo",
      "typ": "two"
    },
    {
      "name": "twunolabelo",
      "typ": "two"
    }
  ]
}
```

If a single `MyData` element comes with 3 different labels i need to emit 3 `MyData` elements with a unique label and then i can do `.keyBy(_.label)` .

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by applying `.flatMap` function

```
val packetSource = env
  .socketTextStream("localhost", 7777)
  .map(json => read[MyData](json))
  .flatMap(
    new FlatMapFunction[MyData,MyData] {
      override def flatMap(value: MyData, out: Collector[MyData]): Unit = {
        value.labels match {
          case Some(labels) =>
            for (label <- labels) {
              out.collect(value.copy(labels = Some(List(label))))
            }
          case None =>
        }
      }
    }
  )
  .keyBy(_.labels.get.head.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly You want to replicate Your message for every `label` in `labels`. I think the simplest idea is to simply create another class, say `MyDataSimple` that will only have single `label` and then use `FlatMapFunction` to map `MyData` to `MyDataSimple` like:

```
val myData = ...
myData.labels.map(label => MyDataSimple(label,...))
```

And then You can do something like:

```
val packetSource = env
      .socketTextStream("localhost", 7777)
      .map(json => read[MyData](json))
      .flatMap(new MyFlatMapFunction())
      .keyBy(_.label)
```

Comment: Many thanks Dominik. Your comments as usual extremely useful!
this works for me.

Comment: posted my implementation with flatMap